# Backslash shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I'm using a portuguese language layout in a US keyboard (I bought my laptop there) and because of this I've lost the backslash key. Is there a way to create a new shortcut for backslash using another key on overleaf?

I don't have a numerical keypad, so I can't use Altgr+92, and Crtl+Space is not so useful because only works once per paragraph.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to reassign the key to the character in the new layout. How to do that depends on your OS (Windows/Mac/Linux), searching for 'reassign key' + your OS will probably get you some useful results.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you should better find a system-wide method to remap your keyboard keys to the `\` character.

However, (La)TeX also provides alternative ways to input certain characters in your document. I can see two options here:

1. **Using the special `^^` input processing:** When TeX sees two superscript characters `^^` in the input stream, it parses the following character(s) differently. The sequence `^^x`, where `x` is a character with a character code between 0 and 127, is replaced by the character plus/minus 64 in the same range. In our case `\` has a character code of 92, so the `x`in our case would be the character with code 92-64 = 28. Unfortunately, this lies outside of the range of characters that can be usually printed/input, so this is no option.

   Next, the sequence `^^xy`, where `x` and `y` are hexadecimal digits (`0`...`9`, `a`...`f`) is replaced by the character with the character code represented by the hexadecimal number xy. In our case that would be 92<sub>10</sub> = 5c<sub>16</sub>.

   Our first option therefore is to use `^^5c` instead of `\`.
2. **Using catcodes:** After the first stage of input processing TeX assigns so-called category codes (catcodes) to each character, that influence the further processing of character sequences. For example, `\` is assigned catcode 0 (escape character) by default. Whenever an escape character is read, the following sequence of letter characters (catcode 11) are merged together into a single input token (a control sequence), e.g. the characters `\`,`f`,`o`, `o`, `{`,`}` would become the tokens `\foo`, `{`, `}`.

   Luckily, we can change the catcode of any input character to any other catcode. The syntax for this assignment is `` \catcode`x=`y `` where `x` and `y` are arbitrary characters (special character have to be additionally escaped by `\`).

   Our second option therefore is to use, say, `` \catcode`/=0 `` to make all `/`s from now on escape characters. The initial backslash has to be copied from somewhere else, of course. ;-)

What makes the second option a bit tricky to use is that the new escape character might be misinterpreted in places where we don't expect it. Some older packages use `/` in dates, for example. A date like `2019/07/01` would be tokenized as `2`, `0`, `1`, `9`, `/0`, `7`, `/0`, `1` and TeX would complain that the command `/0` is undefined. So the second method might likely break if used with the wrong replacement character or if used in the wrong places of your document.

We can combine both methods, though: First we work our way through the LaTeX preamble by using method one, then we switch to method two and keep our fingers crossed that things won't break in the rest of the document:

```
^^5cdocumentclass{article}
^^5cusepackage{xcolor}
% load more packages here using ^^5c

^^5ccatcode`/=0
/begin{document}
/textit{Hello world!}
/end{document}
```

outputs

> *Hello world!*

Again, a proper keyboard remapping should be used instead.

Comment: Off-topic. The first time that I see a subscript in StackExchange. Awesome!!